# Akka actor duplicates on restart

Tags: scala, akka

We have an actor that we wish to restart after a certain length of time if it hasn't heard back from another actor.

So we start a schedule message to send `self ! kill` after a certain length of time.

We have then set our supervision strategy to `Restart` on Exceptions.

```
OneForOneStrategy() {
  case exception: Exception =>
    Restart
}
```

The killing and the restarting is working, however it seems to duplicate the actor. So if we leave it running, after the second window of wait time, we see two kill messages and then 4 and then 8 and so on...

Is there something we are missing? Are we not killing the actor correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out we were simply not cancelling our scheduled kill correctly which meant that whenever the actor restarted it created a new schedule thus the increase in kills and restarts.

Hope this helps someone.